# Identifying rows with duplicate entries and adding column values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet which contains user data, of which email would be the unique identifier. I want to find all rows that contain the same email, then add all the values in a different column and output the result on a separate column, on the last row. Let me try to sketch out an example of what I want.

```
**Name**         **Email**        **Number of hours spent**      **Total**
Jane Poe         janepoe@a.com    3
John Doe         johndoe@b.com    4
John Doe         johndoe@b.com    11                             15
Jane Poe         janepoe@a.com    6
Jane Poe         janepoe@a.com    7                              16
```

I figure what I should do is go through the spreadsheet and add the rows containing the same email to an array, then add the values in the number of hours column, but I'm not sure where to even begin. I'm somewhat comfortable with code but perhaps there is a formula that does this in a simple and elegant way, in the sheet?

Comment: Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A somewhat clunky solution I found was creating a new sheet and linking to the first with
=QUERY('Form responses'!A1:D,"select B, SUM(C) group by B order by B",1)

Comment: Do you just want to put the total values in the last "appearance" of the user, or do you want to also remove the duplicates from the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
 "select A,B,sum(C)
  where B is not null 
  group by A,B", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

or perhaps:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:D, 
 "select A,B,sum(C),sum(D) 
  where B is not null 
  group by A,B", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```